# Why does this work: Windows same local admin username and password, able to access other computer?

Tags: passwords, remote-access, windows-server-2008-r2

I've two machines MachineA and MachineB. Both have two local accounts which have same username . Both accounts are local admin on those machines.

If they have same password, I'm able to access `\\MachineA\C$` from `MachineB`.

But if I change any one password above doesn't work. And it prompts for username and password. Now if I provide MachineA\username and password, it then connects.

Why isn't there a prompt for password when passwords are same? I expected passwords to be hashed with random salt, how does windows know passwords are same and authorize access?

These machines are running Windows Server 2008 R2.

PS. I've created following reg key to enable drive access
`HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy` to 1

Comment: This is symmetric challenge/response authentication. It does not behave anything like a normal password. In particular, salted hashes can't be used for the stored password. (How could you ensure two endpoints used the same salt? And if they didn't, how could they tell that the password was correct?)

Comment: David brings up a really good point using a Salt would not make sense.  Even if a salt would be used the Salt could not be random and thus generated by any application that knew how the Salt was generated.  This is the reason local users shouldn't be used if you deal with computers on a network.

Comment: Does that mean windows just hashes passwords and compares hashes in above case?

Comment: Just adding another related question: https://serverfault.com/questions/205872/how-to-access-files-over-a-network-using-local-accounts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you log in, Windows takes your entered password and stores its LM and NT hashes in kernel memory, in order to provide this single-signon function on workgroups and NT4 domains. (On Active Directory domains, the Kerberos TGT obtained during login is stored as well.)

User-space programs cannot access these hashes directly<sup>1</sup>, but they can ask the kernel to connect to a SMB server using the stored password/ticket, or to perform [NTLM challenge-response](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTLM#Protocol) or [Kerberos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_(protocol)) authentication on behalf of the program (for other protocols such as IMAP or HTTP).

Also, Windows NT uses *unsalted* MD4 hashes for both local authentication and NTLM, but this is not important – it could just as well keep the plain-text password in memory if it was necessary.

---

<sup>1</sup> There is a tool [WCE](http://www.ampliasecurity.com/research.html) which, given sufficient privileges, can examine kernel memory and display the stored credentials.